# Converting linq select into model, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I i'm doing this linq expression in an web api but then it gives this error
    LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'WebApplicationAPI.Models.Registo convertToRegisto(WebApplicationAPI.Models.TBS0017)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Here's the code:

```
var tBS0017 = from row in db.TBS0017
              where row.Cartao == cartao && row.Data == data

var teste = tBS0017.Select(x => convertToRegisto(x));

public Registo convertToRegisto(TBS0017 x)
{
        string term = db.ba_terminal.Where(y => "00"+y.terminal_id.ToString() == x.CodTerminal).Select(y => y.terminal_name).ToString();
        string emp = db.TG0006.Where(y => "00"+y.IdCompanhia.ToString() == x.IdCompanhia.ToString()).Select(y => y.DsCompanhia).ToString();

        Registo r = new Registo() { Cartao = x.Cartao, Data = x.Data, Hora = x.Hora, Local = term, Empresa = emp };
        return r;
}
```

Comment: try to change ``tBS0017.Select(x => convertToRegisto(x));`` to ``tBS0017.ToList().Select(x => convertToRegisto(x));``

Answer (score 1):

Bring `tBS0017` back into memory with `ToList()`

```
var results = tBS0017.ToList()
                     .Select(x => convertToRegisto(x));
```

However, this has some serious flaws.

For every element in `tBS0017`, you are doing 2 more db query's. You should really be doing this in the one query and projecting to `Registo`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that using Linq to Entities tries to convert your C# code into equivalent SQL which can run your query. There is no function "convertToRegisto" in SQL so this gives you an exception.

You can solve the issue by using ToList() to bring the result of the query into memory first. Then you're able to use your methods in the Select.

```
var teste = tBS0017
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => convertToRegisto(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert int value from linq to sql. You must use the sql function that convert int to string values. On the other hand, in memory handling is quite heavy operation 
e.g

> string term = db.ba_terminal.Where(y => "00"+
>   SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)y.terminal_id) ==
>   x.CodTerminal).Select(y => y.terminal_name).ToString();